# How to use variable into a public static php?

Tags: php, repository

I have an upload file script in `/var/www/u/repofolder`. I want to load this link from a variable not from text `$dir = ''`.

```
<?php
$path = "/var/www/u/";
$repo = "repofolder";
$all = $path.$repo;

class gatorconf {


public static function get($param) {

    $config = array(


    'repository' => $all,   instead    'repository' => '/var/www/u/repofolder',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its impossible to do like you want. See here [Variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)  and [Static Keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

> NOTICE: in your case, variable `$all` is not static.

You can define you path like:

```
$path = "/var/www/u/";
$repo = "repofolder";
define('PATH',$path.$repo);

//....

$config = array( 'repository' => PATH );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it available in your `gatorconf` you could just make class variables

```
<?php


class gatorconf {

private $path = "/var/www/u/";
private $repo = "repofolder";
private $all = $path.$repo;

public static function get($param) {

    $config = array(


    'repository' => $this->all,
```